# Detecting function parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, result-of

I went about with the following code to detect the long argument to a given function.

So, given:

```
int f(int *) { return 0; }
```

I want to extract `int *`.

Here is my attempt:

```
template<class T, class U> struct SingleArg {
    typedef U MyArg;
};

template<class T, class U> SingleArg<T, U> fT(T (*p)(U));

int main() {
    std::result_of<decltype(fT(f))>::type::MyArg t;
}
```

This however does not work and gcc 4.6 gives error

```
> error: std::result_of<SingleArg<int, int*> >::type has not been
> declared
```

So, I have two questions:

a) What's wrong with the above code?

b) Is it possible to do this in any other way/ways?

Comment: "function return type", "detect the long argument". What do you really want to?

Comment: Yup. Want to detect the function parameter type. Will modify the post title

Comment: Have you considered `boost::function_traits`?

Comment: @Angew: We don't use boost in our environment

Comment: `decltype(fT(f))::MyArg`? Why even use `result_of`? It does something completely different (and has a different usage syntax).

Comment: @Xeo: gcc refuses to accept that syntax. I used typeid on that and it prints the correct structure name.

Comment: Meh, compiler bug. `template<class T> using Alias = T; Alias<decltype(fT(f))>::MyArg`. If GCC 4.6 doesn't have using aliases, use a `template<class T> struct identity{ typedef T type; }` and then `identity<decltype(fT(f))>::type::MyArg`.

Comment: @Chubsdad: maybe I'm missing something.. result_of<> expects a function as it template argument but struct SingleArg is actually passed. So. indeed, std::result_of<SingleArg >::type is undefined

Comment: Out of interest, what's the purpose of detecting the type?  If there's a way to accomplish your bigger goal without this, I'd recommend it.

Comment: This is not doable in general. Which happens to not be a problem because it is not useful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int f(int *) { return 0; }

template<class T, class U> struct SingleArg {
    typedef U MyArg;
};


template<typename T> 
struct the_same_type
{
 typedef T type;   
};

template<class T, class U> SingleArg<T, U> fT(T (*p)(U));

int main() {

    int k;
    the_same_type<decltype(fT(f))>::type::MyArg t= &k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great!. Marking this as the answer as this was the first correct response

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Function>
struct arg_type;

template <class Ret, class Arg>
struct arg_type<Ret(Arg)> {
  typedef Arg type;
};


int f(int *) {
  return 0;
};

int main(int, char**) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<int*, arg_type<decltype(f)>::type>::value, "different types");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```c
// if you want the type
typedef decltype(fT(f))::MyArg theType;

// if you want the name (may need demangling depending on your compiler)
std::cout << typeid(decltype(fT(f))::MyArg).name() << std::endl;
```

For demangling, see e.g. `abi::__cxa_demangle`.

Comment: does not work for me. Gcc complains 'expected initializer before 'thetype'

Comment: ok... i'm using `Apple clang version 4.0` with `-std=c++11`, i don't have a C++11-enabled g++ version to test with.